# Firebase cloud functions: How to handle multiple triggers caused by another cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a web app on Firebase and have the following Firestore schema and data structure:

```
  db.collection('users').doc{{userid}) // Each doc stores data under 'userinfo' index, which is an object(map).
  db.collection('posts').doc({postid}) // Each doc contains 'userinfo', which is the data about the person who posted.
  db.collection('saved').doc({userid}) // Each doc stores data under 'saved' index, which is an array of carbon copy of a document in 'posts' collection.
```

I am thinking about writing below cloud functions:

-Cloud function A: Listen to updates in one of the docs in the 'users' collection, and update each of the docs in 'posts' collection with the previous userinfo.

-Cloud function B: Lisen to updates in one of the docs in the 'posts' collection, and update each of the docs in 'saved' collection which contains the previous postinfo.

The complication here is, the cloud function A, once triggered, will update multiple documents in the 'posts' collection, each of which will again be a trigger. If the user has written 100 posts, then there can be 100 triggers at once.

To handle such case, which of the following is the natural next step for me? Asking because the answer would depend on how Firebase Cloud Functions handle this kind of situation, but I don't have much knowledge on that at the moment:

a) Write function B as a transaction, because Firebase Cloud Function will handle this situation, by queuing each of the triggers in some order.

b) Write function B to still listen to the update and reflect it to the 'saved' collection, but not as a transaction to avoid massive backlogs caused by database lockups.

c) Rethink the database structure and/or cloud function logic to avoid such situation from the beginning.

There might be a right or wrong answer (or is there one in this case?), but just wanted to get some guidance on direction before actually writing the codes. Any advice? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I have a similar question. Have you been able to find anything?